# vibrations of higher dimensional drums

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

The solutions of the wave equation for a circular drum with fixed boundary are well known.  What do the solutions look like for a spherical drum in three spatial dimensions?  What about higher dimensions?

Comment: You're asking about eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on a sphere.  The keyword "spherical harmonic" will be useful in your search.


Comment: The 3d "drum" is a ball and is fixed on the boundary (sphere).  So solutions will be time dependent functions on the 3d ball which are constantly 0 on the spherical boundary.

Comment: Sorry.  I meant (Dirichlet) eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on the ball.  Take e.g. section 10.3 in Strauss.